# What Excel formula to use?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I ONLY have 2 column which is the "date" and "number". I really don't know how to explain it but for example in the date column, i have "12/20/2019" with corresponding number of "123". I want to lookup if the "123" is in the date of the next working day of "12/20/2019"

Comment: Could you provide a sample or picture about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the screenshot.

[image]

The same value for the next workday is shown by red arrows. Workdays are colored in green.